# How can I read text in a .dat file from the website in java?

Tags: java, android

I'm using java and trying to read .dat file from the web site but it doesn't work.
What I've tried is:

```
URL url = new URL("http://myExample.com/Example.dat");
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
```

I put example url there, but in my code it does have existing .dat file and in that dat file it has full of text.

It doesn't even show an error, I was trying to see what the error is but in the `catch` statement, it says `null`.

Could I get a piece of advice please? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not showing enough code to determine what is wrong. But for reference, the following works:

```
URL url = new URL("http://google.com");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    //print line
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it had an error when i did the BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));

Comment: You cannot just follow up with "it had an error". What was the error?!

Comment: which exception it is throwing or you catching generic Exception or some specific exception... if you are catching Generic Exception be specific and try to catch that exception which these method possibly could throw... you can what exception they could throw in documentation